# Jquery: using closest selector issue

Tags: jquery, closest

I am trying to learn some jQuery and working through some tutorials. I am very early in the process and learning to move through the DOM with `.parent()`, `.parents()` and `.closest()`.

I was chugging a long and then became perplexed as to why I couldnt select a certain element (`p` tag with a class) and add a class to it.

Mind you.. these are just exercises.. I wouldnt select something this way but I want to see that it can be done.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <h2>This is a tutorial</h2>

    <p class="para">This is a tutorial for jquery and jquery UI</p>


<div class="container">
    <ul class="listItem container">
        <li>Hello 1</li>
        <li>Hello 2</li>
        <li>
            <ul class="nest">
                <li>Nest 1</li>
                <li>Nest 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
//$('ul.listItem').find('li').first().addClass('listItem2');
//$('li').parent().removeClass('listItem');
$('ul.nest').children('li:first').addClass('listItem');
$('ul.listItem').closest('.container').removeClass('container');
$('ul.listItem').children('li:nth-child(2)').addClass('listItem3');
$('ul.listItem').closest('.para').addClass('listItem2');


//console.log($('ul').parents('.container'));
console.log($('ul').closest('.container'));
console.log($('ul.listItem').closest('.para'));
```

My question is why will it not select the `p` tag in this example and add the class `listItem2` to it?  It finds the container tag just fine but not the `p` tag, or even the `para` class.  In the console log it shows nothing, but yet finds the container class just fine. Just thought I should know before moving on. Thanks

Comment: closest goes up the DOM tree, in your example, the `p` tag is one of the ul tags parent's siblings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.closest()` searches all the parents of an element (and even the element itself) for a match.

```
$('ul.listItem').closest('.para')
```

This doesn't work because `.para` isn't a *parent* of the `ul`.  The `ul`'s parent's are the two `.container` divs (and I guess the `<body>` and `<html>` tags).

To select the `<p>`, you can do:

```
$('ul.listItem').parent('div.container').prev('.para')
```

Comment: Ahh.. Got it!   I assumed it just went up the page and selected any p tag above.  I guess I assumed that everything above it would be a parent starting at the body tag.  This makes sense though.  Thanks!